# Too long base64 using Python Twitter Api

Tags: python, api, twitter, base64

I'm trying to develop a twitter bot using python which post tweets automatically. By the moment, I can also post strings but I also want to publish images which are in base64. The problem is that when I try to tweet the image in base64 I have an error:

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 205, in update_status
    return bind_api(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 253, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 234, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 431
```

I have read something about this error and it`s relationated with the length of the codification. Here you have the code:

```
import tweepy

def publicarTweet(datos, bufGrafico):
    apiKey= "xxx...xxx"
    apiSecret= "xxx...xxx"
    accessToken= "xxx...xxx"
    accessTokenSecret= "xxx...xxx"


    autenticador= tweepy.OAuthHandler(apiKey, apiSecret)
    autenticador.set_access_token(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)

    api= tweepy.API(autenticador, wait_on_rate_limit=True)


    api.update_status(status="I`ve post this tweet with my bot", media_data= bufGrafico)
```

> The variable bufGrafico is the base64 image

Comment: Please provide snippet of code which caused described error

Comment: Thanks, I have just put it for you!

Comment: did you try with smaller image? Error means problem HTTP headers (which may send image) because HTTP may have restriciton for size of data.

Comment: what module do you use? Based on documentation [update_status](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#API.update_status) doesn't have option `media_data` but `media_ids`. But it has [update_status_with_media](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#API.update_with_media). It looks like you use some different module or maybe older version.

Comment: I have used the inforamation I have find in https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload and the module that I have use in python is tweepy